# Binding TextBox to part of a string

Tags: c#, binding, textbox

I have a string that is saved to a database that is compiled by two textboxes and separated by `.`  e.g. if one `TextBox` has `2` and the other has `5`, `2.5` gets saved to the database.

The issue I have now is with loading saved answers.  Is there anyway to bind `TextBox.Text` to just a certain character of a string (i.e. the first textbox will always be `SavedAnswer[0]` and the other will be `SavedAnswer[2]`) or will I have to create a converter, pass in the full answer and then parse it?

Comment: I think this would do (or maybe i did not understand):

textBox1.Text = savedAnswer[0].ToString();
textBox2.Text = savedAnswer[2].ToString();

Comment: SiLo's answer is the way to go. In general, a View-Model is a logical model of your View; its responsibility is to convert data from your Model into bindable properties for the View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could go about it. The easiest way would be to make your model have two related properties that you bind to separately. The important part is to make sure that they have their `PropertyChanged` events fired so the `Binding` works properly on the UI to reflect changes.

Example:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  string fullAnswer;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public string FullAnswer
  {
    get { return fullAnswer; }
    set
    {
      if(string.Equals(value, fullAnswer)) return; // skip for equal values

      fullAnswer = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("FullAnswer");
      OnPropertyChanged("Answer1");
      OnPropertyChanged("Answer2");
    }
  }

  public string Answer1
  {
    get
    {
      if(fullAnswer == null) return null;

      var tokens = fullAnswer.Split('.');
      if(tokens.Length < 1) return string.Empty;

      return tokens[0];
    }
  }

  public string Answer2
  {
    get
    {
      if(fullAnswer == null) return null;

      var tokens = fullAnswer.Split('.');
      if(tokens.Length < 2) return string.Empty;

      return tokens[1];
    }
  }

  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

    if(handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it's exactly what I need. Question, will an exception be thrown when calling `Split` if there is no value before and/or after `.` (i.e. text has not been entered into both TextBoxes) yet?

Comment: Thanks! I was going to use `str.Length()` to determine if there were values entered, I didn't even think about counting the tokens; much cleaner!

Comment: No problem. It's still slightly inefficient since it is doing the `string.Split()` at least twice (once for each sub-answer property). Not to mention that it is not caching the result, so each time the property is retrieved via `get` it will do the `string.Split()` once again. Fortunately, that shouldn't be very often since `Binding` only will get the value once it notices a change.

Answer (score 0):

Assumin your string is named "str" and always contains the "." caracter:

```
TextBox1.Text = str.Split('.')[0];
TextBox2.Text = str.Split('.')[1];
```

Or:

```
string[] SavedAnswer = str.Split('.');
TextBox1.Text = SavedAnswer [0];
TextBox2.Text = SavedAnswer [1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these three properties.

```
public string FullNumber
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DecimalPart)) {
            return IntegerPart;
        } else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(IntegerPart)) {
            return "0." + DecimalPart;
        }
        return IntegerPart + "." + DecimalPart;
    }
    set
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            IntegerPart = "";
            DecimalPart = "";
        } else if (value.Contains(".")) {
            string[] parts = value.Split('.');
            IntegerPart = parts[0];
            DecimalPart = parts[1];
        } else {
            IntegerPart = value;
            DecimalPart = "";
        }
    }
}

public string IntegerPart { get; set; }
public string DecimalPart { get; set; }
```

`FullNumber` can be used to get and set the full number and thus would be used when reading the number from the DB or saving the number to the DB. The `IntegerPart` and `DecimalPart` properties would be bound to the two textboxes. If you don't want to use databinding, you can drop these two properties and replace `IntegerPart` by `textBox1.Text` and `DecimalPart` by `textBox2.Text` everywhere in the code of the `FullNumber` property.

This works whether the number is empty or `null` and whether it includes a decimal point or not.